# Fundamentals of Game Programming in C

Tags: c, gtk

During the last 2 months I've been trying to learn the basics of game programming. So I coded a few simple games in Java to learn the fundamentals, such as Tetris, Checkers and Pac-Man.

Now I want to learn/improve my skills in C, so I have this idea of writing those games in C to learn more about memory management, no OOP, etc. I have done basic C programming before but never with graphics, so I don't know where to start.

Which libraries should I use to write simple 2D games in C? GTK+? Cairo libraries? Any tutorials you can recommend? Graphics libraries?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would recommend using the SDL graphics libraries, there are some pretty good tutorials and demonstrations here... http://www.libsdl.org/ and for tutorials here... http://www.sdltutorials.com/ Hope it goes well!

Answer (score 3):

Doing some openGL with glut is a good place to start in my opinion, as it allows you to do both 2d and 3d graphics.

http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/glut_downloads.php

If you want another layer to help you with various parts of game programming (keyboard and mouse events, sound, etc..) you can use SDL with openGL.

http://osdl.sourceforge.net/main/documentation/rendering/SDL-openGL.html

There are lots of tutorials around the web to help get you started.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do C game development, OpenGL with glut is a good start..

The [red book](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/) is your friend!!

Comment: OpenGL works very well for 2D and 3D. In both cases, though, you need to be very precise to set up a usable (for whatever definition of usuable you might be using) coordinate system. Once you get your head around the math, though, you're good.

Comment: blue book opengl superbible is quite decent, I recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

Although the following are not 2d; as everyone is mentioning 3d i might add the following libraries; they are open source libraries for 3d engines.

[Ogre](http://www.ogre3d.org/) is a pretty popular open source graphics engine. "Torchlight" was written in it, and so was "A tale in the Desert". Also [the unreal engine has gone open source](http://www.unrealtechnology.com/).

Answer (score 1):

A 2D library that just crossed my mind and is amazing to use is Quartz from OSX. The tools are pretty damn good as well. You'll have to learn some Obj-C though, but its a nice language.

Answer (score 1):

As someone mentioned you need some key Math skills to move up in the game programming world. I don't know how much is involved in animation and modelling since tools are available, but to write engines of any sort Linear Algebra is involved; this applies to  3D programming and it might be involved in 2D Opengl. **Gilbert Strang's introductory book on Linear Algebra** is **amazing**. Mit opencourseware also has an entire semesters worth of lectures available by Gilbert Strang on Linear Algebra. You can download them directly from Itunes or on the web.